# Font style in header and footer LaTex

Tags: header-footer

How do I change font style and size of my header and footer in LaTex to \normalfont\bfseries\sffamily

Comment: You can do that either with `fancyhdr`, or with `titleps` which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: Can you help me with a sample code?

Comment: Sure, but please post a small complete document that I can play with.